# Why is "a =(b>0)?1:0" better than "if-else" version in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

Could you tell me why

```
a =(b>0)?1:0
```

is better than

```
if (b>0)a=1; else a =0;
```

version in CUDA? Please give details. Many thanks.

Yik

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In general, I would recommend to write CUDA code in a natural style, and let the compiler worry about local branching. Besides predication, the GPU hardware also implements "select" type instructions. Using talonmies's framework and sticking in the original poster's code, I find that the same machine code is produced for both versions with the CUDA 4.0 compiler for sm_20. I used -keep to retain intermediate files, and the cuobjdump utility to produce the disassembly. Both the ternary operator and the if-statement are translated into an FCMP instruction, which is a "select" instruction.

The sample case examined by talonmies is actually a special case. The compiler recognizes some common source code idioms, such as the particular ternary expression frequently used to express max() and min() operations, and generates code accordingly. The equivalent if-statement is not recognized as an idiom.

```
__global__ void branchTest0(float *bp, float *d) 
{         
    unsigned int tidx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
    float b = bp[tidx];
    float a = (b>0)?1:0;
    d[tidx] = a;
} 

__global__ void branchTest1(float *bp, float *d)
{
    unsigned int tidx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
    float b = bp[tidx];
    float a;
    if (b>0)a=1; else a =0;
    d[tidx] = a;
}

code for sm_20
        Function : _Z11branchTest1PfS_
/*0000*/     /*0x00005de428004404*/     MOV R1, c [0x1] [0x100];
/*0008*/     /*0x84009c042c000000*/     S2R R2, SR_Tid_X;
/*0010*/     /*0x94001c042c000000*/     S2R R0, SR_CTAid_X;
/*0018*/     /*0x10019de218000000*/     MOV32I R6, 0x4;
/*0020*/     /*0x20009ca320044000*/     IMAD R2, R0, c [0x0] [0x8], R2;
/*0028*/     /*0x1020dc435000c000*/     IMUL.U32.U32.HI R3, R2, 0x4;
/*0030*/     /*0x80211c03200d8000*/     IMAD.U32.U32 R4.CC, R2, R6, c [0x0] [0x20];
/*0038*/     /*0x90315c4348004000*/     IADD.X R5, R3, c [0x0] [0x24];
/*0040*/     /*0xa0209c03200d8000*/     IMAD.U32.U32 R2.CC, R2, R6, c [0x0] [0x28];
/*0048*/     /*0x00401c8584000000*/     LD.E R0, [R4];
/*0050*/     /*0xb030dc4348004000*/     IADD.X R3, R3, c [0x0] [0x2c];
/*0058*/     /*0x03f01c003d80cfe0*/     FCMP.LEU R0, RZ, 0x3f800, R0;
/*0060*/     /*0x00201c8594000000*/     ST.E [R2], R0;
/*0068*/     /*0x00001de780000000*/     EXIT;
        ....................................


        Function : _Z11branchTest0PfS_
/*0000*/     /*0x00005de428004404*/     MOV R1, c [0x1] [0x100];
/*0008*/     /*0x84009c042c000000*/     S2R R2, SR_Tid_X;
/*0010*/     /*0x94001c042c000000*/     S2R R0, SR_CTAid_X;
/*0018*/     /*0x10019de218000000*/     MOV32I R6, 0x4;
/*0020*/     /*0x20009ca320044000*/     IMAD R2, R0, c [0x0] [0x8], R2;
/*0028*/     /*0x1020dc435000c000*/     IMUL.U32.U32.HI R3, R2, 0x4;
/*0030*/     /*0x80211c03200d8000*/     IMAD.U32.U32 R4.CC, R2, R6, c [0x0] [0x20];
/*0038*/     /*0x90315c4348004000*/     IADD.X R5, R3, c [0x0] [0x24];
/*0040*/     /*0xa0209c03200d8000*/     IMAD.U32.U32 R2.CC, R2, R6, c [0x0] [0x28];
/*0048*/     /*0x00401c8584000000*/     LD.E R0, [R4];
/*0050*/     /*0xb030dc4348004000*/     IADD.X R3, R3, c [0x0] [0x2c];
/*0058*/     /*0x03f01c003d80cfe0*/     FCMP.LEU R0, RZ, 0x3f800, R0;
/*0060*/     /*0x00201c8594000000*/     ST.E [R2], R0;
/*0068*/     /*0x00001de780000000*/     EXIT;
        ....................................
```

Answer (score 24):

There was a time when the NVIDIA compiler used idiom testing to generate more efficient code for the ternary operator than if/then/else constructs. This is the results of a small test to see whether this is still the case:

```
__global__ void branchTest0(float *a, float *b, float *d)
{
        unsigned int tidx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
        float aval = a[tidx], bval = b[tidx];
        float z0 = (aval > bval) ? aval : bval;

        d[tidx] = z0;
}

__global__ void branchTest1(float *a, float *b, float *d)
{
        unsigned int tidx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
        float aval = a[tidx], bval = b[tidx];
        float z0;

        if (aval > bval) {
            z0 = aval;
        } else {
            z0 = bval;
        }
        d[tidx] = z0;
}
```

Compiling these two kernels for compute capability 2.0 with the CUDA 4.0 release compiler, the comparison section produces this:

```
branchTest0:
max.f32         %f3, %f1, %f2;
```

and

```
branchTest1:
setp.gt.f32     %p1, %f1, %f2;
selp.f32        %f3, %f1, %f2, %p1;
```

The ternary operator gets compiled into a single floating point maximum instruction, whereas the if/then/else gets compiled into two instructions, a compare followed by a select. Both codes are conditionally executed - neither produces branching. The machine code emitted by the assembler for these is also different and closely replicates the PTX:

```
branchTest0:
    /*0070*/     /*0x00201c00081e0000*/     FMNMX R0, R2, R0, !pt;
```

and

```
branchTest1:
    /*0070*/     /*0x0021dc00220e0000*/     FSETP.GT.AND P0, pt, R2, R0, pt;
    /*0078*/     /*0x00201c0420000000*/     SEL R0, R2, R0, P0;
```

So it would seem that, at least for Fermi GPUs with CUDA 4.0 with this sort of construct, the ternary operator does produce fewer instructions that an equivalent if/then/else. Whether there is a performance difference between them comes down to microbenchmarking data which I don't have.

Answer (score 4):

In general you need to avoid *branches* in CUDA code, otherwise you may get *warp divergence* which can result in a big performance hit. `if`/`else` clauses will normally result in branches based on a test of an expression. One way of eliminating branches is to use an expression which can be implemented without branches if the compiler is smart enough - that way all the threads in a warp follow the same code path.

Comment: "if the compiler is smart enough" That's the main point. IMHO, the compiler should be able to compile it to without-branch operations, whatever way you write it. The compiler must know to avoid branches, and optimize accordingly.

Comment: You do not need to avoid all branches, that just makes the code far more complex than it needs to be. You should have a good understanding of your code and take steps to minimise divergence. A uniform branch (where all threads take the same route) does not have a performance hit. A short branch can be implemented with predication, with minimal performance hit. Long divergent branches are the only case that incur a penalty - lifting common subexpressions out of the branches can help, as the programmer you have a much better understanding than the compiler of how expressions can be refactored.

Comment: I agree with Tom. "You do not need to avoid all branches, that just makes the code far more complex than it needs to be." If the divergent branch code section takes only a small percentage of entire code, the overhead will be minimal.

Comment: @devnglee: that is why I prefixed my statement with "In general...". In general it *is* a good idea to avoid branches, but as with any generalisation one has to exercise one's judgement in each case.

Comment: @PaulR: Branching is a basic programming block, providing a simple but powerful way to modify control flow. I thought it would be more helpful to tell people to use branching with as few amount of warp divergence as possible, or with no warp divergence, than to tell people to avoid branching in general.

Answer (score 3):

In both cases the compiler is going to try to do the same thing, it will aim to use predicated execution. You can find more information in the CUDA C Programming Guide (available via the [website](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)) and also on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predication). Essentially for short branches such as this the hardware is able to emit instructions for both sides of the branch and use a predicate to indicate which threads should actually execute the instructions.

In other words, there would be minimal performance difference. With older compilers the tertiary operator sometimes helped, but nowadays they are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for running the experiment - changed to indicate the difference is minimal. If the kernel is just doing the assignment over again then it would be noticeable but hopefully he's doing something far more interesting than that!

Comment: @Tom Agreed. This whole question stems from an "optimize as you write" mindset, which will significantly reduce your productivity and probably have other negative effects. However, if you *do* happen to be tuning a code path that your profiler says is a high percentage, then yes, see if ternary operator is less cycles :-)

Answer (score -2):

Don't know for CUDA, but in C++ and C99, using the former you can initialize a const variable.

```
int const a = (b>0) ? 1 : 0;
```

Whereas with the latter, you cannot make your `a` variable const as you have to declare it before the `if`.

Note that it could be written even shorter:

```
int const a = (b>0);
```

And you could even remove the parenthesis ... but IMHO it does not improve reading.

Comment: I heard from one of the specialist who told me "a = (b>0) ? 1 : 0;" could improve performance in CUDA. I am very confused.

Comment: It's nothing to do with consts - it's about eliminating branches in SIMT code.

Answer (score -2):

I find it easier to read. It's immediately obvious that the purpose of the whole statement is to set the value of `a`.

The intent is to assign `a` to one of two values, and the ternary conditional operator syntax lets you have only one `a =` in your statement.

I think a standard if/else all on one line is ugly (regardless of what it's used for).

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense for improving appearance. Someone told me that it improves performance as well.

Comment: It's not about code clarity, it's about performance in a SIMT architecture such as CUDA where you get warp divergence on conditional blocks.

Comment: No reason you can't have performance _and_ code clarity (at least in this case). And that syntax is familiar to anyone from a C, Java, JavaScript or C# background (amongst others).

Comment: @nnnnnn That may be true, but this question is specifically about code *efficiency* and this doesn't answer that question.

Comment: @DavidYoung - At the time I posted this answer, the question did *not* mention efficiency, it simply asked which version was "better". The part about efficiency was edited into the question two *years* later, and the edit came from a different account. Now that it has been brought to my attention I'm thinking of rolling back that edit - a way-after-the-fact edit that makes existing answers wrong is not appropriate.

Comment: @nnnnnn Ahhh, my mistake. Also, wow, that's a long time for someone to come in and change the question!